# How to change weight of an object in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, physics

I know some ways to change how quickly an object can we affected [traslation] and such, but how can I change the overall weight so it gets affected differently by gravity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realtime mass changes can be accomplished with the "Edit Object" actuator (my fav) set to *Dynamics*>*Set Mass*.

[image]

However, this *still* doesn't make the object fall faster(Galileo found this ~a long time ago :D)! think, what is gravity, it's a force, right? So applying *more* force means an object falls faster. If an object is dynamic or rigid body, you get alot more buttons to play with under "Motion". Try adding a force on the -Z axis, remember, 9.80 = 1G. Make sure to uncheck the "L" for local; that way you fall down, not toward your feet. Although they are sometimes the same place, if the player gets flipped, you have problems.

[image]

Comment: This isn't getting my character to fall any faster, thank you for the help though.

Comment: oh, yeah, i was just posting that as a compliment to @gandalf3 s answer

Comment: @blackhole is your character a dynamic or rigid-body physics type?

Comment: Dynamic, I thought it would be the same for rigid-body though, I am looking to apply this for both.

Comment: If it's RigidBody or Dynamic, you could add a motion actuator set to force and just specify how powerful you want it to fall. Adding to answer

Comment: @blackhole editted

Answer (score 4):

Heavier objects don't fall faster, so you shouldn't be changing the mass. instead decrease the damping factor ( which is like air resistance when falling ) and the object will go faster. also if there is a way to change the gravitational force effect on this object it would work if you increase it.

[image]

Comment: This is just damping. It makes the effect of it being heavier, but now the object slides a ton. I can get the object only a little bit heavier too. Thank you though.

Comment: to solve the sliding, turn up friction in the material physics tab. As for teh "I can only get it a little heavier" this needs an amendment of the entire scene, turn up gravity and damping on everything else by the same ratio, but leave your fall-fast obj damping at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Change the *Mass* in *Properties > Physics*:

[image]

Comment: I've already tried that, it doesn't seem to affect the object. Any suggestions?

Comment: @blackhole In what way do you want the object to be affected?

Comment: @blackhole Do you mean that you want to make it fall faster?

Comment: @Denis yes, I would like it to fall faster.

Comment: @blackhole The speed at which objects fall doesn't depend on their weight; it depends on the aerodynamics of the object in question (assuming the object is falling through air).